# hibernate 4.x unable to load super class entity column names if calling class uses lombok @Data annotation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, lombok

Hi I'm using lombok api with entity class having @Data annotation which extends audit class (common columns) which is simple abstract class with @MappedSuperclass annotation. But when hibernate-jpa loads, it is not picking up the column names but instead its picking up actual member variable names.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "TEST_TYPES", schema = "TESTER")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = {"id"})
public class TestEntity extends AuditEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
    private Short id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;    
}


    @MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3487394229267512541L;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_ID", length = 40)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", length = 7)
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
```

}

Problem:
Hibernate throwing this error..
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "TESTPROJJU0_"."CREATEDBY": invalid identifier

Expected:
hibernate should pick the column name ie "CREATED_BY" but it is picking up "createdby"

I appreciate any suggestion/help.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with JPA's naming strategy. Setting the property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

should take the actual column names you provided.

Comment: thanks for your response. But your suggestion supports for hibernate 5.0 and above. But i'm using hibernate4.x

Comment: ok, better add it to your question, others might also suggest hibernate5 stuff

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the name using `@Column` annotation.

Comment: Hi Niver I'm using @Column annotation on getters which is fine.

Comment: `@Column(name = "CREATE_ID"` shouldn't this be `@Column(name = "CREATED_BY"`?